# (tap) will cause (press) event in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic3

i am using (tap) and (press) event.but when I was tap after few second press automatically call. can you please help me how to resolve this issue.

and this issue arises only in a device, not in the browser.

see here is my code :

`<ion-card [ngClass]="{‘bg’: item.is_read==0}" *ngIf=“item.is_read != 2” (tap)=“click(…)” (press)=“selectrecord(…)” >`

please correct me if i am wrong anywhere in code.

Comment: you should use (click) and (press). do not use (tap) it’s no longer a thing as hammer blends taps into click event now

Comment: @SergeyRudenko okay, I will try with a click.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko but in ios tap not working.can you please guide me

Comment: can you share the code that you implemented with click? please describe what does not work in ios